# Determine DH params from remote server

Tags: python, diffie-hellman, pyopenssl

is it possible to determine the SSL DH parameter bit size via Python?

I searched for days, but there is not single answer in the whole Internet.

The native OpenSSL can do this. Why not with Python?

Comment: Maybe you need to file a feature request against Python for the native callbacks.